# Heroku: Push to Heroku from local directory instead of GitHub repository

Tags: git, heroku, github

I have an app whose code is in a github repo. I also have a heroku instance that hosts this repository. I can push to it by just committing and doing

```
git push heroku master
```

What I want to do is the following:

1. Commit the local changes
2. Push to the heroku but NOT to the repository

So basically something like

```
git push heroku [from local directory instead of master]
```

Is this possible? I am new to this kind of thing so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always do your work in a local branch which you can create by

```
git checkout -b localbranchname
```

And then push to your heroku master by the command

```
git push heroku localbranch:master
```

And all your work on this local branch will be pushed to heroku's master branch and will not get commited to you repository.

You can always switch between you local branch and master branch using the checkout command

```
git checkout branchname
```

When you do

```
git push heroku localbranch:master
```

this means that you are pushing to heroku's master branch and from your local branch

Comment: Thank you for the explanation on branches. Helped guide me and got everything done.

Comment: This answer implies that `git push heroku master` will send whichever branch is currently checked out to the `master` branch of the remote. That's not true: you need to either merge the branch into `master` or use `git push heroku yourbranch:master`.

Comment: Puzzles me why this answer was accepted.  As the other answers explained,  when you push to heroku it's your local git repo that gets sent upstream, not the one on github.

Comment: Thank you @stvnrlly  for pointing the mistake. I really missed that!

Comment: getting error like error: src refspec localbranch does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'heroku'

Answer (score 3):

Heroku doesn't require that push to the remote repository on GitHub before deploying. The following explanation comes from [this full how-to](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#creating-a-heroku-remote):

> Branches pushed to Heroku other than master will be ignored by this
>   command.
>
> If you’re working out of another branch locally, you can
>   either merge to master before pushing, or specify that you want to
>   push your local branch to a remote master. To push a branch other than
>   master, use this syntax: `$ git push heroku yourbranch:master`

So to Zepplock's point, you don't have to push to your GitHub remote at all, just the Heroku remote.

```
$ git remote -v 
origin  https://github.com/basho-labs/riak-mesos.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/basho-labs/riak-mesos.git (push)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/riak-mesos.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/riak-mesos.git (push)
$ git push heroku master
```

^ If your remotes are set as outlined above, you would push your *local* copy of `master` to Heroku, not the `origin` master. Alternatively, you could choose a different branch:

```
$ git checkout -b not-master-branch
$ git push heroku not-master-branch:master
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `git push heroku master` you are in fact pushing your local code/branch.

If you want to push from other branch than `master` you need to checkout that branch locally first and then do a push.

Comment: But the idea is that I don't want to over-write what I have in the github repository. I want to just push the local stuff without touching the github repository itself. Will doing git push heroku master do this?

Comment: ``git push heroku master`` only affects heroku and not github master. Once you get it working on heroku you can do ``git push origin master`` and it'll update your github repository.